# Can maven-assembly-plugin use the manifest from a dependency?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Is there a way to make `maven-assembly-plugin` use the manifest from a particular dependency as the manifest for an assembled jar?

I'm packaging my app as executable jars with different sets of dependencies, so I'm building the assemblies in separate modules. I've duplicated this configuration in the `maven-assembly-plugin` of each assembly module:

```
<archive>
    <manifestEntries>
        <Main-Class>mypackage.MyApp</Main-Class>
        <SplashScreen-Image>images/splash.jpg</SplashScreen-Image>
    </manifestEntries>
</archive>
```

I'd like to only define this once in the `maven-jar-plugin` of my main module, and use the main module's manifest in all the assembled jars.